# Scala - Type Mismatch Found Unit : required Array[Int]

Tags: scala, types, mismatch

Why does the method give a compile error in NetBeans

( error in question -- Type Mismatch Found Unit : required Array[Int] )

```
  def createArray(n:Int):Array[Int] =
  {
      var x = new Array[Int](n)
      for(i <- 0 to x.length-1)
        x(i) = scala.util.Random.nextInt(n)
  }
```

I know that if there was a if clause - and no else clause - then why we get the type mismatch.

However, I am unable to resolve this above error - unless I add this line

return x

The error is not happening because the compiler thinks what happens if n <= 0
I tried writing the function with n = 10 as hardcoded

Thoughts ?

Comment: The last statement `for` in your function returns `Unit`, but return type is `Array[Int]`. Hence the error. So just put `x` as the last statement in the function. Check @Lee's answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Your `for` comprehension will be converted into something like:

```
0.to(x.length - 1).foreach(i => x(i) = scala.util.Random.nextInt(i))
```

Since `foreach` returns `()`, the result of your `for` comprehension is `()`, so the result of the entire function is `()` since it is the last expression.

You need to return the array x instead:

```
for(i <- 0 to x.length-1)
        x(i) = scala.util.Random.nextInt(n)
x
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another one,

```
def createArray(n: Int): Array[Int] = Array.fill(n) { scala.util.Random.nextInt(n) }
```

Then, for instance

```
val x: Array[Int] = createArray(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something cleaner in my own opinion using yield :

```
def createArray(n:Int):Array[Int] =
  (for(i: Int <- 0 to n-1) yield scala.util.Random.nextInt(n)).toArray
```

This will make a "one lined function"